# A sure shot method to find if SDCard is present

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

[Android check for SD Card mounted always returns true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790182/android-check-for-sd-card-mounted-always-returns-true) 
My question has been asked earlier also & as there were no satisfactory answers, I am stuck. My requirement is very simple.
 I am working on an app where I need to ask the user to select a storage to save in app downloads. I need a method that confirms that external SDcard is present.
 Have already tried following methods:

This is always returning true probably owing to this reason: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7790228/3475715

```
final Boolean isSDPresent = Environment.getExternalStorageState().
                      equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
```

Following is also not working coz maybe the hard coded path is different for different mobiles

```
File file = new File("/mnt/extSdCard");
    try {
        File list[] = file.listFiles();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
         "Yes sdcard is mounted,file count " + list.length,
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (NullPointerException o) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
         "Sorry no sdcard is mounted:", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Sorry but there is no reliable way to check if a micro SD card is present in your device. The best option is to examine getExternalFilesDirs(). If you get two locations the second one is mostly on the card.

Comment: `to select a storage to save in app downloads.` .But why should that be on tne micro SD card. You can just use external storage for it. And why should the user choose to begin with?

Comment: The user is will be able to download video files ranging from 60MB - 2GB so i need to provide an option for SD Card in case user is running on low internal.

Comment: @SMagic please accept my answer if you found it useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [getExternalFilesDirs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDirs(java.lang.String)) method. This method returns path(s) to both internal memory & Micro SD card (if present). The second returned path would be path of Micro SD card. But that path may not be *root directory* of Micro SD card.

`getExternalFilesDirs` introduced in  API level 19 is the only **official** method that can be used to get SD card path. All others methods will return either public or private storage locations(paths) of internal memory.

I have tested this method on my phone & emulator. Kindly, note that I have passed `null` as parameter for `getExternalFilesDirs` during testing. But You could also pass parameter(s) like `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES`, `Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES` etc.

**TEST RESULTS:-**

When **my phone has memory card inserted,** `getExternalFilesDirs` returned :

1st path (internal memory): `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/my_package.appname/files`

2nd path (Micro SD): `/storage/sdcard1/Android/data/my_package.appname/files`

**Note:** root directory of my SD card is: `/storage/sdcard1`

**On my emulator,** `getExternalFilesDirs` returned :

1st path (internal memory): `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/my_package.appname/files`

2nd path (Micro SD): `/storage/11E9-4214/Android/data/my_package.appname/files`

**Note:** On emulator, SD card is emulated(not real one).

**If Micro SD card is ejected (either on phone or emulator)** `getExternalFilesDirs` returns `null`

1st path (internal memory): `path to internal memory - It varies depending on device`

2nd path (Micro SD): `null`

**BUT ;**

On some devices, **you may not get the Micro SD card path.** It means `getExternalFilesDirs` will return only one path(internal memory). Second path would be empty i.e. it will not return any second path.

**Reason:** OEM of that particular device may not have set the path (i.e. `SECONDARY_STORAGE` environment variable) in the device.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33388603/2818583) for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33350250/2818583) says,

> the OEM must have set the SECONDARY_STORAGE environment variable in
>   the device specific `init.rc` file as mentioned here:
>   https://source.android.com/devices/storage/config-example.html

Also the comment made by *somesh* on the above mentioned [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33388603/2818583) says,

> If that environment variable is not set, you can't write to the sdcard
>   by making use of `getExternalFilesDirs` since its not going to return
>   the sdcard path.

In those kind of cases, assume that memory card is not present and save whatever you want to save in internal memory.

**To Summarize**, If `getExternalFilesDirs` doesn't return second path or returned second path is `null`, don't store in SD card (store in internal storage); else store in second path returned by `getExternalFilesDirs`

**Suggestion:**

To understand about different storage locations in Android, please go through [my answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38813578/2818583)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and hats off for the effort.

Comment: Thanks AnV, this clears up many of the questions I had. Although, I'm not sure if it is safe to assume that the second item in `getExternalFilesDirs()` is **always** the SD card - is it not possible for `getExternalFilesDirs()` to return more than 2 items? How do I decide which one is the SD card then (pre-lollipop without Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated(File))?

Answer (score 1):

Android does not expose any API that allows you to get the path of the sdcard root path. You can use reflection and obtain the sdcard root path from StorageManager.java -> getVolumePaths() - http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/storage/StorageManager.java#590

You cannot arbitrarily save to any location on the SD Card. You can either use one of the paths returned from getExternalFilesDirs or use SAF(Storage Access Framework) to explicitly request for user permission to write to SD Card. [How to use the new SD card access API presented for Android 5.0 (Lollipop)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744842/how-to-use-the-new-sd-card-access-api-presented-for-lollipop)